# How to make a search results page with pg_search multisearch that has links to the results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, full-text-search, multiple-tables, pg-search

I finally figured out how to implement pg_search's multisearch feature.  But I'm having trouble making a usable search results page that displays links back to the various articles and faqs that contain the search terms.  It's a pretty basic setup using Rails 3.2.3:

**Models:**

I have an Articles and a Faqs model, both with "Title" and "Content" attributes, and this code in both models:

```
include PgSearch
multisearchable :against => [:title, :content]
```

**Search Form View Code:**

The search form passes everything to a controller called "results."

```
<%= form_tag result_index_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query] %>
  <%= submit_tag "GO", name: nil %>
<% end %>
```

**Results Controller:**

```
class ResultController < ApplicationController
  def index
     @pg_search_documents = PgSearch.multisearch(params[:query])
  end
end
```

I would like to make a search results page that displays the title of each result found, with a link back to that item.  I figured out how to pull the 'class' attribute out @pg_search_documents.  My thinking is to do something like this on the results page:

```
<ul>
<% @pg_search_documents.each do |pg_search_document| %>
  <li><%= link_to pg_search_document.searchable.title, "../#{pg_search_document.searchable.class}/#{pg_search_document.searchable.id}" %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

An example link that this code yields is: `http://localhost/Article/3`.  If I could figure out how to downcase and pluralize "pg_search_document.searchable.class", I'd be home free.  I've tried writing various methods in the model and controller, and tried writing a helper.  But this is where my Rails skills fail me.

Any suggestions?  Anybody know of a more elegant way of accomplishing this?  Any ideas / suggestions are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did something similar and just used

```
<%= link_to pg_search_document.searchable.title, pg_search_document.searchable %>
```

to let Rails dynamically create the path to the associated record.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's amazing what walking away from the problem for a little while does.  That, and more persistent Googling on basic Ruby.  Here's the solution I came up with:

```
<ul>
  <% @pg_search_documents.each do |pg_search_document| %>
    <li><%= link_to pg_search_document.searchable.title, "../#{(pg_search_document.searchable.class).to_s.downcase!.pluralize}/#{pg_search_document.searchable.id}" %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Still, this seems ugly to me.  I'd still be very interested to see something more streamlined and intelligent.